# Distorted video in Windows Media Player ActiveX

Tags: .net, video, activex, windows-media-player, codec

I'm trying to play MKV (Matroska format) file in Windows Media Player ActiveX control.

While it plays perfectly fine in standalone WMP, the embedded control fails to render the video properly. Image appears with many little squares and no actual picture.

The required codec is properly installed. All other formats don't cause any problems.

An attempt to play in WPF MediaElement control resulted in the same behavior, as it uses WMP ActiveX internally.

I'm wondering if it's a know bug and any workaround is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue only occurs on Windows 7 due to automatic use of Microsoft codecs for H.264 decoding. It can be solved by configuring preferred DirectShow filters to ffdshow in the registry.

Comment: is there an example of the reg key that needs to be set?

Answer (score 1):

There could be some problem with your codecs.. [try reinstalling them](http://www.mediaplayercodecpack.com/).. cause I just made a small app to check it out and it smoothly played 1080p .mkv video.